# SassError: Invalid CSS, wants expression instead of function

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, node-sass

I have 2 files, "styles.scss" and "_themes.scss" respectively:

```
@use "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@use "themes";

body {
  background-color: themes.get(primary);
}
```

```
:root {
  --color-primary: #666666;
  --color-primary-variant: #999999;
  --color-on-primary: #000000;
}

@function get($color-name) {
  @return var(--color-#{$color-name});
}
```

The IDE (WebStorm 2021.1) shows no errors itself, however, upon attempting to compile it, I receive this message:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss- 
loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src
/styles.scss)

SassError: Invalid CSS after "...d-color: themes": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".get(primary);"
        on line 16 of src/styles.scss

>>  background-color: themes.get(primary);
```

Just in case it was my file extensions, I made another version using `.sass`, only to be met with the same error. Is there an issue with how I apply `@use "themes"` where I cannot do `themes.get(primary)`? I tried using `@import "themes"` for `get(primary)` but it doesn't change anything.

Further information if applicable: I am using React along with React-Bootstrap and Bootstrap.

Comment: node-sass doesn't support `@use`

Comment: It appears I have been doing it all wrong @disinfor. Oddly enough, when I tried `@import` as an alternative before, it still had an error, but it's working correctly now. Thanks!